# How to read JSON data from web and insert insert into database

Tags: java, insert, http-post, jax-rs, crud

When I am retrieving, I am getting data only for first row; that is one object only getting retrieved.

In this case empNo = 3 data is not getting retrieved.

/* I am using JAX_rs Functionality, and PostMan to test data.

Below is the code for insertion I am using */

**Postman Sample Data**

```
[ {
        "empNo": "2",
        "empName": "roy",
        "empRole": "Software"
    },
    {
        "empNo": "3",
        "empName": "sri",
        "empRole": "Software"
    }
]
```

// Model Class

```
package com.employee.employeeModel;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {

    private String empNo;
    private String empName;
    private String empRole;

    /*
     * public Employee() // Default DeConstructor
     * {
     * 
     * }
     */

    /*
     * public Employee(String empNo, String empName, String empRole) // Parameterized Constructor
     * 
     * { 
     * this.empNo =  * empNo; this.empName = empName; this.empRole = empRole; }
     */

    public String getEmpNo() {
        return empNo;
    }

    public void setEmpNo(String empNo) {  //instance method
        this.empNo = empNo;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public String getEmpRole() {
        return empRole;
    }

    public void setEmpRole(String empRole) {
        this.empRole = empRole;
    }
}
```

// Method for Inserting –

```
public static  Employee addEmployee(Employee emp2) {

    int status=0;

    try {
        Connection connection = EmployeeConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement( "INSERT INTO employee VALUES(?,?,?)");


        ps.setString(1, emp2.getEmpNo());
        ps.setString(2, emp2.getEmpName()); 
        ps.setString(3,emp2.getEmpRole());
         status =  ps.executeUpdate();
         System.out.println(status +"row inserterd sucessfully" );
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) { System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); 

    }

        return emp2;

}
```

// Service Class for POST Method

```
@POST
@Path("/Submit")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Employee  addEmployee(Employee emp)
    {

            return EmployeeData.addEmployee(emp);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postman you submit multiple Employees (array), but your endpoint and DAO method work with only one instance of Employee `addEmployee(Employee emp)`.

You need to modify endpoint/DAO to handle `Employee[]/List<Employee>`.

**Update: added endpoint to handle multiple employees**

```java
@POST
@Path("/employees")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public List<Employee> addEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
    List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        result.add(EmployeeData.addEmployee(employee));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Add the above-mentioned code snippet with appropriate `import` statements and test your newly added `/employees` API endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.. Can you write the code snippet for me .. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sorry, no :) It is something you have to do by yourself.

Comment: HI Alex, Struggling to map elements with model class.. would u suggest how to map the values

Comment: When you submit only one user in a Postman request like this:
`{ "empNo": "4", "empName": "jack", "empRole": "Software" }`, does your app work?

Comment: Yes Alex i am getting .its inserting only one row in data base from the given array